# which API should i use for map display just like that of Nokia drive app?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app which will act very much like "Nokia Drive". Now if u say why not use Google API, The problem with Google API is that it has very poor imagery as compared to that of Nokia Drive. So, Is there any other API that i can use for this? And what about HERE API?? The documentation says these apps(That are using HERE API) can only be run on Devices with NOKIA X services. SO is it so that it won't run in any other android device except Nokia????????? Please Help, I am New to this.